# Weird Inconsistent 404 page

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404, ektron

One returns a custom 404, the other does not.

http://www.budgetblinds.ca/badpage/

http://www.budgetblinds.ca/bad-page/

Fiddler shows that the latter is a 404 but the custom page never shows.

Code behind (notFound.aspx) :

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
Response.StatusCode = 404;
Response.Status = "404 Not Found";
}
```

Web.config:

`<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="generalError.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error404.aspx" />
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/serverError.aspx" />
    </customErrors>`

What else can I do to solve this?

Comment: Have you set a break point to check the workflow ?

Comment: what do you get when you do not get the custom 404 error page?

Comment: @JotaBe I get "This web page is not available" with error code "ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE" in Chrome and in Firefox it says "File not found."

Comment: That doesn't look like a 404 error. Please, check the HTTP Status code of the response. Use the console (press F12) of your browser, or Fiddler to see what's going on.

Comment: With Fiddler, I found that my response is being redirected to a 404 status but the requested page isn't being display properly by showing the user the correct 404 page. @JotaBe

Comment: Please, so the URL. If not, it's impossible to guess!